# JSOM default groups when creating subsite

Tags: groups, client-object-model

```
function createWebsite(siteName, site) {

    this.clientContext = typeof site !== 'undefined' ?  new SP.ClientContext(site) : SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

    var webCreationInfo = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
    webCreationInfo.set_title(siteName);
    webCreationInfo.set_description(siteName);
    webCreationInfo.set_language(1033);
    webCreationInfo.set_url(siteName);
    webCreationInfo.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(false);
    webCreationInfo.set_webTemplate('template here');

    oWebsite.get_webs().add(webCreationInfo);
    oWebsite.update();


    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args){
        alert("Site made");
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args){
        //alert(args.get_message());
    }

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this ,onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
}
```

This function creates a subsite to the specified site, I'm wondering how i enable the creation of default permission groups. That is when i create a subsite manually and decide not to inherit permissions from top site, SharePoint automatically creates three default groups for me (visitor, member, owner). How is this done in Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should manually create those groups and assign permission as below

```
var groupCreationInfo = new SP.GroupCreationInformation();
groupCreationInfo.set_title(siteName + ' Members');
groupCreationInfo.set_description('Member Group');
this.oGroup = oWebsite.get_siteGroups().add(groupCreationInfo);
var collRoleDefinitionBinding = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);
this.oRoleDefinition = oWebsite.get_roleDefinitions().getByType(SP.RoleType.contributor);
collRoleDefinitionBinding.add(oRoleDefinition);
var collRollAssignment = oWebsite.get_roleAssignments();
collRollAssignment.add(oGroup, collRoleDefinitionBinding);
clientContext.load(oGroup, 'Title');
clientContext.load(oRoleDefinition, 'Name');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCreateGroupQuerySucceeded), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

Comment: What are you specifying in these lines? `clientContext.load(oGroup, 'Title');
clientContext.load(oRoleDefinition, 'Name');`

Comment: @ThomasLindauer its same as 'Include(Title'). I got that script from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/hh185014(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection1)

Comment: This certainly creates a group, but how do i set this group to a site and how do i specify to put persons in it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the only missing part in your example is assigning permissions to the Web site.
Use

- [SP.Web.associatedMemberGroup property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245549(v=office.15).aspx) to set the group of users
  who have been given contribute permissions to the Web site
- [SP.Web.associatedOwnerGroup property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245638(v=office.15).aspx)  to set the associated owner
  group of the Web site
- [SP.Web.associatedVisitorGroup property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247047(v=office.15).aspx) to set the associated visitor group of the Web site

**Example**

```
var createTeamSite = function(siteName,success,error) {

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var parentWeb = ctx.get_web();

    var info = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
    info.set_title(siteName);
    info.set_description(siteName);
    info.set_language(1033);
    info.set_url(siteName);
    info.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(false);
    info.set_webTemplate('STS');

    var web = parentWeb.get_webs().add(info);
    parentWeb.update();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            success(web);
        }, error);
}





function logError(sender,args) {
    console.log(args.get_message()); 
}

//usage
createTeamSite('Team Site',
  function(web)
  {
     //Assign pemissions from root web 
     var ctx = web.get_context();
     var rootWeb = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb(); 
     var ownerGroup = rootWeb.get_associatedOwnerGroup();
     var memberGroup = rootWeb.get_associatedMemberGroup();
     var visitorGroup = rootWeb.set_associatedVisitorGroup();

     web.set_associatedOwnerGroup(ownerGroup);
     web.set_associatedMemberGroup(memberGroup);
     web.set_associatedVisitorGroup(visitorGroup);
     web.update();
     ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            console.log(String.format('{0} site has been created',web.get_title()));
        }, 
        logError);
  }
  ,logError);
```

Comment: Please read question again. >That is when i create a subsite manually and decide not to inherit permissions from top site, SharePoint automatically creates three default groups for me (visitor, member, owner). How is this done in Javascript?

Comment: I have to mention, the line 
parentWeb.update();
is not really needed for the website to be created, but then, associating groups would fail! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The code below
1. Creates a website
2. Creates three NEW groups (visitors, members, onwers) if must not inherit permissions
3. Binds permissions for these groups
4. Associates the groups with web's properties

```
function createWeb(weburl, webname, webdesc, template, inheritBool) {

var latestNewWeb,
    latestNewGroup,
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
    defaultCallback = oncreateWebsiteSucceeded,
    parentWeb = clientContext.get_web(),
    collWeb = parentWeb.get_webs(),
    webCreationInfo = new SP.WebCreationInformation();

webCreationInfo.set_title(webname);
webCreationInfo.set_url(weburl);
webCreationInfo.set_description(webdesc);
webCreationInfo.set_webTemplate(template);
webCreationInfo.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(inheritBool);
latestNewWeb = collWeb.add(webCreationInfo);
if (!inheritBool) {
    defaultCallback = createDefaultGroups;
}
parentWeb.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(defaultCallback, oncreateWebsiteFailed);

function createDefaultGroups() {
    createVisitors();
    // all other group creations will occur as callbacks;
}

function createVisitors() {
    createGroup(
        "Visitors", "Visitors Group",
        SP.RoleType.reader, "set_associatedVisitorGroup",
        createMembers, oncreateWebsiteFailed
    );
}

function createMembers() {
    createGroup(
        "Members", "Members Group",
        SP.RoleType.contributor, "set_associatedMemberGroup",
        createOwners, oncreateWebsiteFailed
    );
}

function createOwners() {
    createGroup(
        "Owners", "Owners Group",
        SP.RoleType.administrator, "set_associatedOwnerGroup",
        oncreateWebsiteSucceeded, oncreateWebsiteFailed
    );
}

function createGroup(title, description, SPRoleType, assocFn, callbackOk, callbackHell) {

    var groupCreationInfo = new SP.GroupCreationInformation(),
        collRoleDefinitionBinding,
        oRoleDefinition,collRollAssignment;

    groupCreationInfo.set_title(webname + " " + title);
    groupCreationInfo.set_description(description);
    latestNewGroup = latestNewWeb.get_siteGroups().add(groupCreationInfo);
    collRoleDefinitionBinding = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);
    oRoleDefinition = latestNewWeb.get_roleDefinitions().getByType(SPRoleType);
    collRoleDefinitionBinding.add(oRoleDefinition);
    collRollAssignment = latestNewWeb.get_roleAssignments();
    collRollAssignment.add(latestNewGroup, collRoleDefinitionBinding);
    clientContext.load(latestNewGroup);
    clientContext.load(oRoleDefinition, 'Name');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            assocGroup(assocFn, callbackOk, callbackHell)
        },
        callbackHell
    );
}

function assocGroup(assocFn, callbackOk, callbackHell) {
    latestNewWeb[assocFn](latestNewGroup);
    latestNewWeb.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(callbackOk, callbackHell);
}

function oncreateWebsiteSucceeded() {
    say("Created Web site: " + weburl);
}

function oncreateWebsiteFailed(sender, args) {
    say('Fail. ' + weburl + " --- " + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}}
```

Comment: just a notice, someone could prefer using groupCreationInfo.set_title(weburl + " " + title);
instead of 
groupCreationInfo.set_title(webname + " " + title);
I know I would!